# Sequelize simple query don't give plain object

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm only starting with sequelize and don't judge strictly. 
I have couple of models:
amount of work for booking

```
export function initAmountOfWork(sequelize: Seq) {
return sequelize.define('amount_of_work', {
    booking_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    room_type_id: {
        type: Sequelize.SMALLINT,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    cleaning_type_id: {
        type: Sequelize.SMALLINT,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    amount: Sequelize.SMALLINT,
}, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: false
    });}
```

roomtypes

```
export function initRoomTypes(sequelize: Seq) {
return sequelize.define('room_types', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.SMALLINT,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    room_type: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true
    });}
```

and also cleaning types which is similar.
I have also this associations

```
 AmountOfWorkModel.hasOne(RoomTypesModel, { foreignKey: 'id' })
RoomTypesModel.hasOne(AmountOfWorkModel, { foreignKey: 'room_type_id' })
    AmountOfWorkModel.hasOne(CleaningTypesModel, { foreignKey: 'id' })
CleaningTypesModel.hasOne(AmountOfWorkModel, { foreignKey: 'cleaning_type_id' })
```

I can make a query like:

```
function getAllWorksByBookingId(bookingId: number) {
    return AmountOfWorkModel.findOne({
        where: {
            booking_id: bookingId,          
        },
        raw: true
    })
```

and i get a result like

```
{
  "booking_id": 23,
  "room_type_id": 2,
  "cleaning_type_id": 7,
  "amount": 1
}
```

The question is how to form a query which generate me the object with letter types from "roomtypes" and "cleaning types" tables corresponding to id from my "amount of work".  Like:

```
  {
    "booking_id": 23,
    "room_type_id": "big room",
    "cleaning_type_id": "standart cleaning",
    "amount": 1
  }
```

I also tried to use include, but have no idea, how to use it twice in one table, because a lot of syntax mistakes.
Also I have an idea to make also two another queries to get corresponding names from tables of types, but I have a feeling that it's stupid idea.
Sorry for such ridiculous question, I searched a lot of time for similar query but haven't find, and I forced to ask the question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `attributes` to extract only the name column. you can then access the value using `.`. For multiple include, the syntax is as follows.

```
...

include : [
{model : model1},
{model : model2}
],
```

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely what I was looking for!